# Can somebody tell me what this sorting algorithm is called?

Tags: sorting

So my teacher told me about the bubble sorting technique and it looks like it runs too many times, so I came up with this, I'm fairly sure that it's already been made and I want to know what it's called.

Here it is:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, k = 0, i, min, aux;
    cout << "N:";cin >> n;
    int v[n];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    cin >> v[i];
    do{
        for(i=k;i<n;i++){
            if(i==k)
                min = i;
            if(v[i] < v[min])
                min = i;
        }
        aux = v[k];
        v[k] = v[min];
        v[min] = aux;
        k ++;
    }while(k<n-1);

    cout << "\n";
    for(i=0;i<n-1;i++){
        cout << v[i] << ",";
    }
    cout << v[n-1] << ".";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called selection sort. Good job coming up with it on your own, you can read about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort).